# How to find stored procedures not used in data layer code?

Tags: c#, sql-server

We have a C# application with data access code written in C# that calls stored procedures in SQL Server.

I noticed some of the stored procedures are no longer called by the data access code. Is there a way we could find those stored procedures and delete them?

We tried the `dm_exec_procedure_stats`, but since this application is still in staging phase we found the stats to be unreliable.

Comment: If you have a REPO in GIT you can take the SP name and search the repo if it is used or not.  If you have a lot of SP's that may not be the best but it would work.

Comment: We use TFS and Visual Studio. We do have a lot of stored procs.

Comment: You could create Extended Events that track anytime an SP is used and then use that to see what is being used (but if something is not called while your Extended Events scanning is running you will miss those (like SPs called infrequently)

Comment: Just because it's not called doesn't mean it's not used. Why do you wanna delete them, running out of text space?

Comment: @siggemannen There are stored procedures that are not used/called at all.

Comment: how do you know? maybe users just don't press all buttons :)

Comment: Do any of your stored procedures call other stored procedures? I could just see second-level dependencies disappearing and causing errors. Or service brokers broken because, you know, the queue receivers aren't called by application code. What's the real problem you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for an application that is actively used:

1. Configure extended events to record each instance of stored procedure call (OR use can use SQL Server Profiler to achieve the same)
2. Enable [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16#About) to monitor query performance. Query store [views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) can be used to retrieve `object_id` of an object (SP, UDF, Trigger etc.) that the query belongs to.

I would suggest Query store as it also lets you monitor overall database performance as well as identify unused code.

As was pointed out in the comments you do need to run this process for a long time (a month or more) to ensure that all "rare" events are captured.

Once unused objects are identified I suggest quarantining them (by renaming them) for a few months before finally removing them.

If your application is still in development then the best way is (as @Brad suggested) is static code analysis. It does get somewhat involved though if you have stored procedures calling other stored procedures. PowerShell should help you automate this thought.